# Matlab's plot function with Qt C++ program

Tags: c++, matlab, qt, math, plot

I just want to connect my Qt C++ GUI application with Matlab to draw plots. I just want the equivalent Qt C++ instructions for this code:

```
data=importdata('C:/Users/Eden/Desktop/Mydata.txt');
x=data(:,2)
y=data(:,3)
plot(x,y)
```

And if it's possible I want to know to connect Qt interface with Matlab.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Metaprogram a matlab script into a .m file and run it? Actually it might work very well. I've seen a pdf utility for matlab doing it this way: it uses matlab to metaprogram ghost script to work with pdf files.

Comment: Can you explain more please? thanks :)

Comment: Just write above code to a .m file using C++ and somehow call matab to run that script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use that function from MatLab then I think it's a bit too complicated for this small scenario but you can build a stand alone application in MatLab and call that from your C++ application. But for this task it may be easier to write your own Plot object in C++ with Qt.